# On KDE how to change taskbar's font size?

Tags: kde, fonts, plasma, taskbar

I have a problem.  I installed the newest Ubuntu and KDE (Ubuntu 16.04 and plasma 5.5.5), may I know how to change font size in the taskbar? I already tried on irc: #plasma but the answer ( "the taskbar follows system settings -> fonts -> general" ) just didn't work :(

**Edit:**

One more thing, I know other people don't have this issue, i.e. the above solution works, it's only me, probably in the entire world, who deals with this issue. So, something, for some reason overwrites this option imho.

Answer (score 0):

As of KDE Plasma 5.24.7, to change the taskbar font, you need to launch System Settings, then go to <kbd>Appearance</kbd> -> <kbd>Fonts</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I managed to get to the Settings Window using the `systemsettings` command.Then, I went to `Application Settings` and altered whatever i wanted from there including the taskbar.